# HP PA-RISC loading symbol table in gdb

Tags: gdb, debug-symbols

I have a binary of file format "PA-RISC2.0 shared executable". And a core dump by running this binary. I have the stack trace. To get more information I am trying to extract the symbol table and load it in gdb session.

The problem is I am not able to extract the symbol table PA-RISC2.0 SOM file format. The commands 'odump' and 'nm' output the symbol table in ascii text, which not loadable by the gdb.

In Linux, for ELF-file formats it is possible with 'objcopy --keep-only-debug' to extract the symbol table.

Is there any way to extract the symbol table from an executable of the above file format.

Operating system is HP-UX 11i

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to extract the symbol table from an executable of the above file format.

Your question appears to be based on false premise -- that somehow extracting the symbol table info from an executable will give GDB more info than what GDB itself was able to extract from the executable. It *will not*.

The `objcopy --keep-only-debug` is usable when you want to keep the debug symbols, but want to ship a stripped executable to the customer. It is *not* useful when you have a debug executable and a core dump that you want to debug.

Update:

> In gdb if i am able to load the symbol table, I can get the values of local variables which would not be possible if i didnt.

Yes, but you *don't* need to extract the symbol table from the executable into a *separate* file for this -- GDB will load symbol table directly from the executable *on its own*, without any extra steps.

I suspect that you are not invoking GDB correctly. Don't do this: `gdb -c core`. Do this instead: `gdb /path/to/a.out /path/to/core`.

Update 2:

> Yes i do `gdb <binary> <core>`

In that case, perhaps you are missing the `pxdb` preprocessing step? HP-UX versions of GDB automatically run `/opt/langtools/bin/pxdb` to transform debug info into format that GDB understands. But maybe you are using GDB that is too old, or your system does not have `/opt/langtools/bin/pxdb` installed?

Comment: Yes the executable has debug symbols. It is compiled with -g flag. I must be able to extract the symbol table.

Comment: @tsmyelin "I must be able to extract the symbol table" -- What for? What are you hoping to achieve with the result of extraction?

Comment: In gdb if i am able to load the symbol table, I can get the values of local variables which would not be possible if i didnt.

For example: If i try 'info locals' in a gdb session, it gives 'No symbol table'. If i load the symbol table i can get the variable values in that frame.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes i do gdb <binary> <core>. I need to check why its not loading symbol table. Thanks for the help!